# Query required for given case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables one with name, **Employee_Info** which contains *Employee_no, Name* and Department and other table with name **Attendance** which contains *Employee_no* and *Attendance_Date*. Attendance table contains data of those employees who have marked their attendance.
Now I want a query which can help me select those employees who are absent on a specific date in the format as below:

```
Employee_no       Department       Absent_on
10160100000       XYZ              06/25/2021
```

Kindly help!!

Comment: Please post what you have tried and specifically what your issue is. Also post sample data, as text - **no images**, and the expected output of that data.

Comment: If you have some tables and some data it would be better to post table definitions or at least the data and desired output as text. Because someone who answers have to do this before writing and answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. Read comments within code (sample data in lines #1 - 14; query you might want to use begins at line #15).

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  employee_info (employee_no, name, department) as
  4    (select 1, 'Little', 10 from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Foot'  , 20 from dual
  6    ),
  7  attendance (employee_no, attendance_date) as
  8    (select 1, date '2021-09-01' from dual union all
  9     select 1, date '2021-09-02' from dual union all
 10     select 1, date '2021-09-03' from dual union all
 11     -- employee 2 was absent on 2021-09-02
 12     select 2, date '2021-09-01' from dual union all
 13     select 2, date '2021-09-03' from dual
 14    ),
 15  missing_attendance_info as
 16    -- list of employees who were absent
 17    (select e.employee_no, a.attendance_date
 18     from attendance a cross join employee_info e
 19     minus
 20     select b.employee_no, b.attendance_date
 21     from attendance b
 22    )
 23  -- finally, join employee_info with employees who were absent
 24  select m.employee_no, e.name, e.department, m.attendance_date
 25  from missing_attendance_info m join employee_info e
 26       on e.employee_no = m.employee_no;

EMPLOYEE_NO NAME   DEPARTMENT ATTENDANCE
----------- ------ ---------- ----------
          2 Foot           20 2021-09-02

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like this,

```
SELECT EMP.EMPLOYEE_NO AS EMPLOYEE_NO, EMP.DEPARTMENT AS DEPARTMENT, :IN_DATE AS ABSENT_ON
FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO EMP
WHERE
    EMP.EMPLOYEE_NO NOT IN (SELECT EMP.EMPLOYEE_NO
                            FROM ATTENDANCE ATT
                            LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_INFO EMP 
                                ON ATT.EMPLOYEE_NO = EMP.EMPLOYEE_NO
                            WHERE
                                TO_CHAR(ATT.ATTENDANCE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = :IN_DATE);
```